# (Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord::Relation) How to determine whether model has been scoped?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a class method called `sample` that I have mixed in to `ActiveRecord::Base` so that you can call `User.sample`. However, I have a conditional on this method that checks whether the model has been scoped or not. If it has been scoped, for example with `User.where(:verified=>true).sample`, then it will use different logic than the unscoped version `User.sample`.

Another way to put it is I need to check whether the receiver is a `ActiveRecord::Relation` or not. I have tried `self.is_a?(ActiveRecord::Relation)` inside the mixin, but it always returns `false`. It seems as if Rails applies the `sample` method *first* to the unscoped `User`, before applying the `where(:verified=>true)` scope.

In my `sample` method, how do I distinguish whether the receiver is the unscoped `User` or the scoped one such as `User.where(:verified=>true)`?

Specifically, my mixin is:

```
module Sampler
  def self.prepended(model)
    class << model
      self.send(:prepend, ClassMethods)
    end
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def sample(n=1)
      adapter = ::ActiveRecord::Base.connection.adapter_name
      if adapter == 'PostgreSQL' && !self.is_a?(ActiveRecord::Relation)
        # do something else
      elsif ['MySQL', 'Mysql2'].include?(adapter)
        self.order('RAND()').limit(n)
      else
        self.order('RANDOM()').limit(n)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: inside the sample method try `if self.is_a?(ActiveRecord::Relation)`

Comment: @LesNightingill I've tried that already, but it always returns `false`.

Comment: There is some `method_missing` trickery involved where the `ActiveRecord::Relation` object will call the original `ActiveRecord` class for unknown methods. You could check `caller[0]` from within the method but it's ugly..

Comment: Show more code please. Specifically, show your mixin and sample method code. Also can you just confirm which version of Rails you're using, and can you confirm the return of: `User.where("").is_a? ActiveRecord::Relation`

Comment: @smathy I've edited the question to include the actual mixin code. My version of Rails is 3.2. The return value of `User.where("").is_a? ActiveRecord::Relation` in the console is `true` and `User.is_a?(ActiveRecord::Relation)` is `false`.

Comment: Ah ok, and then you're doing a `prepend Sampler` explicitly in each model you want that for?

Comment: @smathy I actually prepend to `ActiveRecord::Base` so that it applies to all models that inherit from Base, but yes, that's the idea.

Comment: Ok, but it won't be a class method on AR::Base, that's why I asked to see all that code. Rails 3 was a long time ago, but the `Array#sample` might have been mixed in back there, and perhaps you're calling that unknowingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveRecord can be pretty byzantine to hack. The following is not quite as concise as you were attempting, but it works! You have to provide a sample method for the scoped and non-scoped scenarios.

```rb
module ActiveRecord
  class Base
    def self.sample(n=1)
      adapter = ::ActiveRecord::Base.connection.adapter_name
      if adapter == 'PostgreSQL'
        # do something else
      elsif ['MySQL', 'Mysql2'].include?(adapter)
        self.order('RAND()').limit(n)
      else
        self.order('RANDOM()').limit(n)
      end
    end
  end
end

module ActiveRecord
  module FinderMethods
    def sample(n=1)
      adapter = ::ActiveRecord::Base.connection.adapter_name
      if ['MySQL', 'Mysql2'].include?(adapter)
        self.order('RAND()').limit(n)
      else
        self.order('RANDOM()').limit(n)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I've edited your answer to put `# do something else` on the unscoped version. On a similar path, let's say I had a method `count` that would use the unscoped version if doing `User.count` but would always use the scoped version whenever there was any scoping on `User` regardless of whether it came before or after. For example, `User.where(:verified=>true).count` and `User.count.where(:verified=>true)` would both use the scoped version. How would I implement that?

Comment: count always comes last b/c it returns an integer, so `250.where(:verified => true)` doesn't make sense. If my answer is working for you, please consider designating it as the "accepted answer"

Comment: Ah! Very true. My mistake about `count`.